# Windows(File Explorer,Disk Mngmnt & Diskpart) and MiniTool and sdcard.org's formatter are unable to format my memory card? Should i dispose the card?

Tags: partitioning, memory

I've tried formating my memory card using Window's File Explorer, Disk Management & Diskpart and MiniTool partition wizard and  sdcard.org's sd car formater, no one touched my memory card, Should i dispose it?

Or any of you legends can save me 6 $'s?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per all my calculations, just dispose this card, it's over for it.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/846563)

Comment: @Burgi This is the OP self answering ...